# Android - Link to other app stores?

Tags: android

In my app there is a rating button. If the user activates this button, the user will be forwarded to the Google Play website to give a review.

```
market://details?id=<package name>
```

Now I uploaded my app to other app stores. And they want, that I must change the Link from the button to e.g.

```
https://www.otherAppStore.com/android?p=<package name>
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm now thinking to make different versions (AndroidManifest.xml). For e.g. for google:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0.1" >
```

and for the other app store:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0.2" >
```

Looks not professional?

Comment: I think you should use `market://details?id=<package name>`

Comment: Oh sorry I meant that for google. This is not the problem. The problem are the other app stores. How can I give different app stores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is the following:

In your manifest in your  tag add a meta-data that includes the url of the store.

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="store.url"
        android:value="market://details?id=<package name>" />
```

Then in your code use this value. Now every time you want to update your app you have to create builds with different `android:value`. You can do some scripting to automate this process.

To retrieve this url:

```
try {
    ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    if (ai.metaData != null) {
        url = ai.metaData.getString("store.url");
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    // if we can't find it in the manifest, do something maybe fallback or runtime exception
}
```

Comment: Same versions e.g. android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" with different android:values?

Comment: Yes it will work. I do not advice you to change the versionName or code just because it is a different market. Anyway using a meta-data will require no change in your java code. So you can script to change the meta-data and rebuild.